# Label - is it required to have the 'for' attribute or an input inside it?

Tags: html

Can I do something like that?

```
<label>{i18n('Avatar:')}</label>
<input type="text" name="avatar" />
```

Mouse click effect is not important for me.

Is it valid in html5 to have label without for attribute and without input inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**HTML5 specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html), it is **not** compulsory for  a `<label>` element to have the `for=` attribute, neither does it necessarily have to include an `<input>` element.

Answer (score -2):

w3c has a validator. You can check here

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.